# Inconsistent ReceiptDeviceId value

Tags: c#, windows-8

I'm using the [ApplicationModel.Store](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229885.aspx) set of classes to obtain a receipt for a Win 8 app purchase. Calling `CurrentAppSimulator.GetAppReceiptAsync();` is giving me the receipt XML and I'm loading that in to an XDocument object.

Each time I run the app and inspect the XML, I see that the `ReceiptDeviceId` attribute has a different value.

Can someone tell me if this is because I'm running this against `CurrentAppSiumulator` vs a published app?

Does anyone know if this value is consistent between re-installs on the same device?

Per the API spec:

> ReceiptDeviceId: Identifies the device used to request this receipt.

This makes me also wonder if this value is driven off the [ASHWID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj553431.aspx) and can change if I plug in headphones etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I heard back from Microsoft regarding this value. It would remain the same regardless of tampering or reinstall of the device.

In particular the ReceiptId will be unique for the user regardless of machine.  The ReceiptDeviceId will be unique PER user on each device.

build talk that may be useful is available at: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2013/3-126